# How to add a .xib GUI to a Command Line Tool App?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, command-line-tool

I am new to OSX development, I have a Command Line Tool app that I am working on. I want to add a GUI(Graphical User Interface such as a .xib) to it so that data can be display nicely. Is it possible to do this? If so, how can I achieve this?

Any comments, suggestions, options are welcome and appreciated. thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a normal cocoa application to get access to the gui. Then in the app you'll use NSTask to run your command line code. Good luck.